# VSCode with activated ssh-agent on Windows 10

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, windows-10, ssh-agent

I want to use git from within VSCode, using my ssh-key. My current working fix is this:

1. start Powershell
2. run start-ssh-agent.cmd (of git installation)
3. run code

This links the ssh agent or socket to VSCode, effectively allowing me to use the key for git commands.

How can I turn this into a proper script? Or even better: How do I start and configure the ssh-agent automatically so it's globally available (similar to ssh-add on linux)?

Comment: It looks like VSCode looks at the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. Running `code.exe` via MinGW (Git Bash) after running `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` worked, so I tried setting `$env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in PowerShell and running `code` with success. Maybe there's a way to start `ssh-agent`, run `ssh-add`, and inject `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on Windows login?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this help tip for VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent

To summarize, run the following from an administrative PowerShell window:

```
# Make sure you're running as an Administrator
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service ssh-agent
Get-Service ssh-agent
```

This should set the Windows ssh agent service to start automatically, so that you don't need to enter your password every time.